# How to declare an immutable variable in Go?

Tags: go, constants, immutability

I was solving some exercises to get some practice in go and came across the
following problem.

Take this function:

```
func foo(s string) {
    length := len(s);

    // Do something just reading from lenght
}
```

Here, thanks to programing in other languages, my mind immediately went "length
will not be modified, so it should be marked const".

So I did this:

```
const length = len(s);
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
const initializer len(s) is not a constant
```

I suppose that is because `len(s)` cant be calculated "at compile time" (Not
sure if this is 100% correct talking about go).

Is there any way to indicate that `length` should not be modified? I searched
in Google, but I found nothing usefull. I got some thins about immutable structs, but
I think its too complex for what I want to do.

Comment: There is no way to define an immutable variable in go. You can define constants, but the value must be evaluated at compile time, hence you cannot do len(s) where s is a variable

Comment: `len(s)` cannot be calculated at compile time because `s` is a variable.  If the mutable variable bothers you,  then use `len(s)` directly instead of declaring a variable.

Comment: The nature of a "variable" is that it is variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot specify a variable to be immutable. Only constants have this property.

Constants in Go are also **compile-time constant**, meaning you can't initialize it to something that depends on the particular value of some variable like `s` in your example.

Also, with [rare exceptions](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof), functions cannot return constants. Even when they can, it must still be a **compile-time** constant. `len` [can return a constant value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity), but only if the parameter is constantly sized, such as a string constant or of an array type (which has fixed length in Go).

Answer (score 2):

For something with similar result, you could use a private field. Make a module
like this:

```
package foo

type Length struct { value int }

func NewLength(s string) Length {
   return Length{
      len(s),
   }
}

func (l Length) Int() int { return l.value }
```

then use like this:

```
package main
import "foo"

func main() {
   l := foo.NewLength("north")
   println(l.Int() == 5)
   // l.value undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method value)
   l.value = 6
}
```